# Integrating SBT continuous testing with IntelliJ

Tags: unit-testing, intellij-idea, tdd, sbt, continuous-testing

SBT supports continuous testing out of the box.  How can I integrate that into IntelliJ, so that IntelliJ shows me the failed tests as they happen (similar to the wonderful NCrunch for .NET)?

Comment: I know this is old but.. have you ever found what you were looking for? I wish IntelliJ IDEA had a plugin for this.

Comment: @GuiSim - No, I wasn't able to find a solution

Comment: This guy found a couple of dead ends: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27172745/continuous-testing-with-intellij-idea

Comment: Not what you're looking for, but I ended up just running them in the IntelliJ console, with `sbt` then `> ~ test`.